# ArgumentException when encrypting data using an ECC CryptographicKey

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to implement an encryption algorithm using the new ECC curves that were added in the UWP framework, but I didn't find any code example on the internet and I'm having an hard time trying to come up with something that actually works.

Here's what I have so far:

```
private static byte[] ConvertHexToBytesArray(String hexString)
{
    IBuffer hexBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromHexString(hexString);
    return ConvertBufferToBytes(hexBuffer);
}

protected static IBuffer ConvertBytesToBuffer(byte[] value)
{
    return CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray(value);
}

protected static byte[] ConvertBufferToBytes(IBuffer buffer)
{
    byte[] result;
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(buffer, out result);
    return result;
}

protected static byte[] ConvertStringToBytes(String value)
{
    byte[] result;
    CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray(CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(value, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8), out result);
    return result;
}

protected static String ConvertBytesToString(byte[] value)
{
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value, 0, value.Length);
}

public static void Test()
{
    // Get the key
    AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider a = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.EcdsaSha512);
    CryptographicKey key = a.CreateKeyPairWithCurveName(EccCurveNames.NistP521);

    // Get the IV array
    const String IV = "FF7234783740D47159A23C432341324F";
    byte[] IVArray = ConvertHexToBytesArray(IV);
    IBuffer IVBuffer = ConvertBytesToBuffer(IVArray);

    // Get the data to encrypt
    String test = "Some random text to encrypt";
    byte[] testBytes = ConvertStringToBytes(test);
    IBuffer testBuffer = ConvertBytesToBuffer(testBytes);

    /* Encrypt the data
    * ====================
    * This line actually throws an ArgumentException */        
    IBuffer encrypted = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, testBuffer, IVBuffer);

    // Decrypt it back
    IBuffer decrypted = CryptographicEngine.Decrypt(key, encrypted, IVBuffer);

    // Get the decrypted String
    byte[] result = ConvertBufferToBytes(decrypted);
    String plainText = ConvertBytesToString(result);
    Debug.WriteLine($"Decrypted: {plainText}");
}
```

Is there a guide on how to implement this thing, and am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks!

Sergio

Comment: Could you please add the message of the `ArgumentException`?

Comment: @Herdo It just says "Value does not fall within the expected range", but I don't know which one of the three parameters is it talking about

Comment: Oh ok. Got the same issue, but with a different algorithm last week. It seems that the algorithms have a maximum length of text/bytes they can encrypt/decrypt. E.g. my asymmetric algorithm is limited to 62 characters. Try to start with a smaller byte count/less text for your `testBuffer`.

Comment: @Herdo I tried to just encrypt "Test" but I had the same Exception, I guess that's not the problem in this case :/